Discard rows with a string value from a dataframe
I have a dataframe like this:



C1
C2
C3
C4




1
foo
asd
23


foo
foo
asd
43


3
foo
asd
1


4
foo
asd
bar



I'm trying to filter (and discard) all rows that have strings in C1 or C4 columns,
my final dataframe must be:



C1
C2
C3
C4




1
foo
asd
23


3
foo
asd
1



I'm trying to do this using "isNaN" but I'm not sure how I should use it.
This is my code:
df = pd.read_csv(
    path_file,
    sep=",",
    usecols=columns,
    skiprows=0,
    skipfooter=0,
    engine="python",
    encoding="utf-8",
    skipinitialspace=True,
    on_bad_lines='warn',
    names=columns)

df_new = df[df["C1"].notna()]
df_new_2 = df[df["C4"].notna()]

Any idea about how I can achieve this?

Please make a reproducible pandas example. It doesn't really matter how you're loading the data, but we need to see the post-loaded data.

You can try something like this:
df.loc[df[['C1', 'C4']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna(how='any').index]

Output:
  C1   C2   C3  C4
0  1  foo  asd  23
2  3  foo  asd   1

Use pd.to_numeric with errors='coerce' to give NaN that can be used to with dropna.

Variant: df.loc[df[['C1', 'C4']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notna().all(axis=1)], which would also work if you have duplicated indices.
